# Nullpointer exception when modifying string through another class - Java

Tags: java, class

In my main method, I am doing this:

```
RTAlgorithm rt = new RTAlgorithm();
String s = "Looooolasdasdl";
rt.encrypt(s);
System.out.println(s);
```

Here is my RT class:

```
package rt.encrypt;

public class RTAlgorithm
{
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    alg_flip(s);
    return s;
}

private static String alg_flip(String s) {
    String s1 = "";
    for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
    }
    return s1;
}
}
```

However, it is giving me a NullPointerException on the rt.encrypt(s) line in the main method i have

Comment: where do you initialise rt?

Comment: Have created an instance of that class? Does rt actually exist? Maybe you should post the code from both classes

Comment: In the `modify` function, shouldn't you be doing e.g. `return alg_flip(s);`?

Comment: Please post full code and stacktrace you are getting

Comment: Should you be doing i--?

Comment: @user1549804 When he fixes his NPE and start returning the changed values he always get _""_

Comment: after your edit, did you not have forgotten to include the modify()-method ? Or did you have renamed it into encrypt() ?

Comment: only sending full `StackTrace` of Exception will help you more ,to get correct answers.

Comment: Two minor remarks: Please give self-explaining names to your variables and parameters (s, s1 will not help you reminding what they're supposed to represent) Java uses lower CamelCase for method naming so `alg_flip` should be renamed `algFlip` ... Have a look at java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Answer (score 4):

If you return a value in your method as in your .modify you have to get the value back:

You're doing:

```
String s = "Looooolasdasdl";
rt.modify(s);
System.out.println(s);
```

You need to do

```
String s = "Looooolasdasdl";
String s2 = rt.modify(s);
System.out.println(s2);
```

And in the modify method you need to get the return of your alg_flip() call

```
public String modify(String s) {
    return alg_flip(s);
}
```

**Edit**

if you use a lot of algorithms you should consider the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

The main problem of your attempt still is you call a method with a parameter, but you don't save what happend which you get from your return statements.

**Edit 2:**

I got your main problem, although the return part is also a problem:

```
for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
}
```

you want to get the chars at i and do a for loop reverse but you add up your i variable

```
for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
}
```

this is what you should do

**This works for me:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        RTAlgorithm rta = new RTAlgorithm();
        String s = "Looooolasdasdl";
        s = rta.encrypt(s);
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}

class RTAlgorithm {
    public static String encrypt(String s) {
        return alg_flip(s);
    }

    private static String alg_flip(String s) {
        String s1 = "";
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
        }
        return s1;
    }
}
```

But if you write static Methods, you don't really need to create an instance.

instead of `rt.encrypt(s);` you could say `RTAlgorithm.encrypt(s);`

Comment: The alg_flip is only one method i want to use, i have several others, this is just a test, how would i implement other methods then?

Comment: in Java Strings are immutable, so, if you pass them as parameters they don't get changed but return the changed version. If you don't return anything you will get always the same 'String'

Comment: String s1 = alg_flip(s);
String s2 = alg_something(s1);
String s3 = alg_else(s2);
return s3;

Comment: I know this code mainly is for "training" purpose but there is a simpler way to flip the string by using StringBuffer or StringBuilder : `return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

The only reason there is

```
rt.modify(s);
```

You forgot to initialize  `rt`  before using it.

Comment: So please post full stackTrace

Answer (score 0):

That means your `rt` variable is referring to `null`. You should create an object which is referred by the `rt` variable as follows.

```
RT rt = new RT();// or whatever your class name is
```

Answer (score 0):

the rt class is not declared. You should insert the line

```
Rt rt = new Rt();
```

before using it.
Besides, there's still an issue you have to be aware of. The alg_flip method does nothing. You take the String s, use it to produce a String s1 and return it. By the way you never do

```
s = alg_flip(s);
```

and so you never push the s1 value inside the s variable.

Answer (score 0):

Main method:

```
String s = "Looooolasdasdl";
String s_modified = rt.modify(s);
System.out.println(s_modified);
```

rt class:

```
String modify(String s) {
  return alg_flip(s);
}

private static String alg_flip(String s) {
  String s1 = "";
  for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
}
return s1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
rt.modify(s); // since modify() is not a static method 
                you have to initialize rt first
```

else you can make `modify()` method static as follows

```
public static String modify(String s) {
alg_flip(s);
return s;
}
```

Now you can access this method `ClassName.modify()`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable objects! So you cant modify a string!

You have to do it like this:

```
String s = "Looooolasdasdl";

//rt.modify(s); //Mistake 1
s = rt.modify(s); //Reassign to s
System.out.println(s);
```

Your RT.class should be:

```
package rt.encrypt;

public class RTAlgorithm
{
public static String encrypt(String s) {

//    alg_flip(s); // Mistake 2: You create the String you want return
    s = alg_flip(s);  //  but you have to reassign it to var s!
    return s;
}

private static String alg_flip(String s) {
    String s1 = "";
    for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
    }
    return s1; //You have to return a new string reference
}
}
```